# Not send data POST from react to php script

Tags: php, reactjs

This is the code in react:

```
fetch(base_url + '/api/test', {
  method: 'post',
  body: {
    hello: 'hello'
  },
  headers : { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(respone => console.log(respone))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

This is code in php:

```
<?php
$info = array('logged' => $_POST['hello']);
echo json_encode($info);
```

Please help me

Comment: please try to check if `base_url` is correct.

And please replace `body` to `data`

Comment: Does your PHP script get any data at all? Does it get executed? Did you try to put a breakpoint e.g. using xdebug and debug the PHP code? What does your browser console say?

Comment: Yes, `base_url` is correct